# Power to dead circuit

Tags: electrical

I have someone replacing my breaker panel in a couple weeks. Its old and the breakers are failing and hard to find. I have one dead circuit that I need to power up. I disconnected the circuit from the breaker, can I power that circuit by an extension cord from a live receptacle to one in the dead circuit?

Comment: Does the critical load have a cord and plug connection?  Could it be made to have one?

Comment: Chances are you can temporarily combine it with another circuit in the panel. Without details, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

In the panel just pull the wire off the dead breaker and put it on a breaker of the same ampacity that is working.

If there is already a wire on that breaker, check if the breaker is listed to accept 2 wires (a few are, e.g. pushmatic).  If *not*, then pull both wires off the breaker, wire-nut them to a 6" pigtail, and attach the loose end of the pigtail to the breaker.

---

The other option, not quite legal, is to get a power cord of same gauge as the circuit. A power cord can be obtained by chopping the socket end off an extension cord.  Have the bare-wire end of the cord enter the panel via a properly sized strain relief.  Pull the hot off the defective breaker and its partner neutral (**must** do both). Nut them to the hot and neutral of the power cord.  Then plug the power cord into any working receptacle.

- Now, why use a flexible cord and not Romex? It's illegal to use Romex for line cord.  And it is illegal to put a plug on Solid wire cable.
- Why make the Romex-cord splice *inside the service panel*?  Because it has to be inside *some sort* of junction box, gutter or panel, *any would do*, just the circuit already goes to the panel.
- Why neutral too? Imbalance of currents / eddy current heating / other badness.  Always have the return current (neutral) in the same cable or conduit as the hot(s).

Comment: BTW: in current breaker lines, CH and QO are both listed for double-tapping, while 1" wide breakers generally aren't.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with option 2 -- if anything, if I had to do a flexible-cord stunt, I'd fit an inlet into a spare J-box and nut up the *socket* side of a cut-in-half cord to the panel, then plug socket into inlet...

Answer (score 0):

As isherwood pointed out - you can probably wire the dead circuit to a live breaker, creating a "double tap" situation.  It's against code but it's temporary and will power the circuit.

It's also safer than running an extension cord from one circuit to another to provide power because you'll potentially overload the circuit you're effectively extending, which could lead to electrical fire.  Double tapping a breaker is not great but is safer because the breaker will trip if overloaded, while wire will just get hotter and hotter.

Comment: If you do this you should tap into a breaker that's the same size or smaller than the one you're removing from not one that's larger.

Comment: Excellent point - never allow the breaker capacity to exceed the wire capacity.

Comment: Putting 2 circuits on 1 breaker is not a code violation if the breaker is listed for 2 wires, if the breaker is not listed for 2 just pig tail the 2 wires with a wire nut and a piece of wire the same gauge or larger to the breaker inside the panel this would be safe and code compliant.